# ширина картинки

Tags: html, css

Возможно, вопрос будет немного наивным, но....
При размещении картинки в div, высота div будет больше чем высота самой картинки. Каким образом можно установить полное совпадение по высоте.
В примере, высота img - 358.8, а div - 362.8
Спасибо

```css
img {
    width: 30%;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

        <div class="img">
          <img class="picture" src="https://w-dog.ru/wallpapers/9/17/322057789001671/zakat-nebo-solnce-luchi-oblaka-tuchi-pole-kolosya-zelenye-trava.jpg" alt="природа">
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`img` по дефолту имеет `display: inline`, из-за чего под картинкой появляется отступ.
Используйте `display: block` для `img`, чтобы это устранить.

```css
.img {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 30%;
}

.img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img class="picture" src="https://i.imgur.com/cTWZv5u.jpg" alt="природа">
</div>
```